# Detect tap gesture on mkmapview that isn't the annotation?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

How do I detect if the mapview is being tapped on, that isn't an annotation in obj-c?

Comment: Strangely, you just add the usual tap detection code - it seems that MapView does not have the concept "built-in"!

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4,

I fixed this in our case,
by adding tap gestures to both annotation view and map view.

add tap gesture to map

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hideFilterView))
self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

//override "viewFor annotation:" something like this
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    var annotationView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Pin")
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Pin"
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = false
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTapPin(onMap:)))
    annotationView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return annotationView
}

//then don't override 
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) { }
```

So the all pins selections will be handled using tap gestures.
And you can detect map and pins tap separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try **UITapGestureRecognizer**:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapDidTap:)];
[mapView addGestureRecognizer: tapGesture];
```

And

```
-(void)mapDidTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    //do something when map is tapped
}
```

Comment: I'm using exactly this code, and mapDidTap: never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

The following code detects a tap in the map and adds a map marker at that location:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *fingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleMapFingerTap:)];
    fingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    fingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:fingerTap];

}

- (void)handleMapFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    NSLog(@"handleMapFingerTap gesture: %@", gestureRecognizer);

    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate =
    [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

    MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    pa.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
    pa.title = @"Hello";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:pa];

}
```